# Operator not working

Tags: php

I have a operator in a string .

```
 $c['operator'] = ">=";

        if($sub_total.$c['operator'].$c['value'])
        {
        echo $sub_total.$c['operator'].$c['value'];

        }
```

it obtain output is `20610>=30000`

Comment: Do you expect it to evaluate the expression? It is just a string.

Comment: That's not supposed to work. Imagine all the security problems it would cause if it did.

Comment: yes, I expect that  it evaluate the expression

Comment: Can you please give more details as to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I assume that @PradeepSingh is building a form which can be used to filter a dataset. For example, the user can enter a field name, an operator and a value much like in Google Analytics report filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd put the possible operators in a `switch`:

```
$result = null;

switch($c['operator'])
{

    case '>=':
        $result = $sub_total >= $c['value'];
    break;
    case '<=':
        $result = $sub_total <= $c['value'];
    break;

    // etc etc

}
```

This is far safer than using `eval`, and has the extra benefit that it sanitises the input.

Answer (score 1):

String can't be interpreted as php code unless you use [`eval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) (be careful with it).

What you are doing in your example in `if` statement is that you concatenate strings and because string after concatenation is not `null` it's evaluated to `true`, so `if` statement is executed.

In your case solution would be to see which operator is used like @adam has written in his solution.

BTW, having logic in strings (and possibly outside of script) is not a good idea.

Comment: "String can't be interpreted as php code." That's wrong. In fact it was quite common a few years ago to evaluate a string as PHP code using [the `eval()`-function](http://php.net/eval).

Comment: @feeela The second paragraph was saying, that. Actually, you are right. I'll edit question.

Answer (score 1):

`$sub_total.$c['operator'].$c['value']` is not a comparison but a string concatenation. A filled string is always true in PHP, hence the `if`-statement is always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to evaluate the code you constructed.

```
$c['operator'] = ">=";

if(eval($sub_total.$c['operator'].$c['value']))
{
    echo $sub_total.$c['operator'].$c['value'];          
}
```

Comment: `eval` is not safe to use, especially with user-generated input

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in PHP, you should do something like below :

```
if ($c['operator'] == '>=' and $sub_total >= $c['value']) {
    // Do something
} else if ($c['operator'] == '<=' and $sub_total <= $c['value']) {
    // Do something else
} // etc...
```

Comment: "You can't do that in PHP" Is there any language where such a construct would give the desired results?

Comment: Yeah that's true, but I don't know all the languages on earth so maybe somewhere a weirdo created one that does this.

Comment: FYI, there are similar things, such as variable function names (`$result()`) and variable variables (`$$result`), but neither are applicable in this case.

Comment: @adam: Yeah, I knew that, and while I find `$func()` very useful `$$var` is weird enough (and particularly useless in my opinion)

Comment: Yeah, can't say I've ever used it! Thought @feeela might find it interesting.

Comment: It's interesting to know that and can explain some weird typo errors. BTW, I think your answer is far more readable than mine

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the eval method. It's very dangerous though

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php